# Salesforce error "returnFieldData Types invalid at this location" using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, salesforce, apex-code, force.com

Hi I am new to Salesforce and Apex programming. I have installed eclipse with salesforce IDE. But it gives me following error (in image) when I try to create a new project using force.com
[(click here to see error screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syt1q.png)

**Error returned:** 
*Unable to fetch organization details for 'username'*
*Element {urn:partner.soap.sforce.com}returnFieldData Types invalid at this location*

**FACTS:**

- I am signed up on a developer.salesforce.com free login
- I have generated new Security token and am surely using the latest
- I am adding correct credentials because when I deliberately enter wrong info it gives me username/password type of error
- I have tried changing different environments when creating new project
- Using Eclipse 4.5.1
- Salesforce 16
- Profile is "System Administrator"

Please help, thank you!

Comment: btw, you haven't stated version of Force.com plugin.

Comment: Force.com version 36

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked my dev sandbox - it runs Winter '16, which is v.35. I assume, your version of Force.com plugin is v.36. Try to uninstall it and install v.35. It might be because of versions incapability.

Comment: it worked like a magic! thanks

What i did is: 
I un-installed force.com plugin version 36 from the eclipse
then re-installed force.com IDE version 35 and then tried to create a new project. it worked!

Thanks again sir!